# Plot hex numbers in pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I want to draw a graph from external text file which contains hex numbers (representing integers) like `0x8210` in 4 columns. It seems `pgfplot` does not automatically recognize the hex numbers. I know that it is possible to convert the hex numbers to decimals, for example, using `lua` in `lualatex`. Is there any way to convert the hex numbers to decimal ones or set an input number format before plotting without using the `lua`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PGF math parser understands hex numbers. However, `\addplot table` does not necessarily apply the math parser to input numbers (it merely tries to read it is decimal number).

In order to activate the math parser within `\addplot table`, you can use `y expr` and its variants:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        minor y tick num=1,
    ]
    \addplot+[nodes near coords] table[x=x,y expr=\thisrow{y}] {
    x y
    0 0x8
    1 0xA
    2 0xF
    3 0x10
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]